# How to play movie infinite number of times using MPMoviePlayerController class?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is it possible to play movie again and again using the MPMoviePlayerController class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK MPMoviePlayer can't play continues loop.
 MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification can be used to start playback again after finish, but it results with  up to 2 second gap between loops.